# Mocha test intermittent result

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I am writing a mocha test to check that after a function runs that the file exists. The results I am currently getting are quite intermittent. It will sometimes pass a few times in a row, but then fail. I am quite new to TypeScript so I am not sure what is going on.

I went through my code and made sure that I was correctly answering promises.

This is the function I am trying to test:

```js
export async function writePackConfig (templateFile: TemplateFile, destination: string, filename: string) {
  LogToConsole('Writing pack config file')
  const mappings = await getPackInfo()
  let content = generateTemplate(TemplateFile.packFile, mappings)
  // writeFileContent(join(destination, filename), content, filename, false)
  await writeFile(join(destination, filename), content, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'wx+' }, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
}
```

And this is how I am testing it:

```js
describe('Testing writePackConfig function', function () {
  let testFolder = join(__dirname, 'writePackConfig-test')
  before('Create testing folder', async () => {
    try {
      removeSync(testFolder)
    } catch {
      console.log('Folder does not exist')
    }
    mkdirSync(testFolder)
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
  before('Create pack.yaml file', async () => {
    let mappings = {
      'ref': 'pack-ref',
      'packname': 'Pack Ref',
      'author': 'Test Author',
      'email': 'example@example.com'
    }
    let stubGetPackInfo = sinon.stub(bootstrapfunctions, 'getPackInfo').resolves(mappings)
    await writePackConfig(TemplateFile.packFile, testFolder, 'write-pack-config-pack.yaml').catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    stubGetPackInfo.restore()
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
  it('Check that file is written when writePackConfig is run', function () {
    let result = existsSync(join(testFolder, 'write-pack-config-pack.yaml'))
    console.log(result)
    assert.strictEqual(result, true)
  })
```

It should return true as the file does exist. However it doesn't all the time. The file is however created each time it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) writes the file asynchronously, then calls the `callback`.  It doesn't return anything.

So this line:

```ts
await writeFile(...);
```

...doesn't actually wait for the file to be written since that line is really doing this:

```ts
await undefined;
```

...which doesn't cause a compile or run-time error, but also doesn't wait for the file to be written.

---

To ensure the test passes consistently you will need to make sure `writePackConfig` returns a `Promise` that doesn't resolve until the file is written.

Node has a new [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) that is currently `Experimental` but does have a [`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) function that returns a `Promise`.

Another option is to use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create a `writeFile` version that returns a `Promise`:

```ts
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as util from 'util';

const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);  // <= This writeFile will return a Promise
```

...then the last line of `writePackConfig` would just be:

```ts
await writeFile(join(destination, filename), content, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'wx+' });
```

...and your test should pass consistently.

Comment: I will take a look and get back to you 

Comment: Thank you so much! That's fixed it. You've come to my rescue again :P. Just wondered though, could I have just used `fs.writeFileSync` instead?

Comment: @RichardAnnand yes, you *could* use `fs.writeFileSync`...just don't bother putting it in an `async` function and trying to use `Promises` with it since it will block the main thread *no matter where it is called* (as demonstrated by the test in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341592/10149510))